# Can I collaborate with Google Sheets offline on multiple devices?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-sharing, google-sheets-offline

Can I do something about this:

I manage multiple teams on sites with little or no signal except the small office WiFi spots. I want to have a copy of a single Google spreadsheet on multiple iPads for each team so they can log progress & merge details later on the office WiFi. The teams will work on separate bits of the sheet so I'm not worried about clashing edits Whilst making the sheet I've noticed that the downloaded copy on my phone is glitchy for offline work ...

- sometimes it won't load on my phone when the phone is offline, saying that it needs to be made available offline. The ‘offline availability’ option is checked on for my test sheet for both phone and laptop, and it’s downloaded onto my phone too.
- repeatedly says that the phone copy can't sync (when the phone's online),
- a couple of times when it was working I lost edits when I came out of airplane mode (for simulation test purposes).

I have Google Chrome & Drive for offline sheets work on my Windows laptop, and the Android Sheets app for my Android phone. Is this teething problems while I write the sheet, hardware problems with my Android phone/ Windows laptop, or a feature of Sheets that it doesn't work well for multiple people offline?